# Also (in the sense of too) could but be put at the beginning of a sentence before the subject?

Tags: grammar

In a formal (IT) report, a sentence like:

> ... the feeding leans temporary on the XYZ. Also the engine output,
>   the ABC, is sent to the XYZ.

is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the feeding leans temporary on the XYZ.

cannot be correct. I am  not sure what the intended meaning is here. "temporary" is an adjective, but the structure here requires an adverb to modify the verb "leans".

> the feeding leans temporarily on the XYZ.

is grammatically valid, but still this uses of "feeding" sounds very odd to me. Could the proper word be "feed" in the sense of "a regular signal, or sequence of information"? I am guessing at a possible meaning here.

Returnign to the point sressed in the question,

> Also the engine output, the ABC, is sent to the XYZ.

and

> Even the engine output, the ABC, is sent to the XYZ.

have subtly different meanings, although both are grammatically correct. The first form, with 'also" means that the ABC is sent in addition to whatever else is sent. It simply states a fact. The second form, with "even" implies a degree of surprise. The ABC is set in addition to everything else, when one would have expected the ABC not to be sent. It also implies that not just some other things are sent, but everything possible.

> John, James, and Jane went to the show. Also George went, but he was late. Jill didn't go.

as opposed to

> John, James, Jill, and Jane went to the show. Even George went, although no one expected him.

Note the difference in meaning.

Comment: You're right, "temporarily" is the word to use. Feeding means "giving the input files".

Comment: I don't want a sence of surprise, hence, is "also", in that position, correct?

Comment: @CarLaTeX  "giving the input files". might be expressed as "the feed" while the form "the feeding" seems unlikely. Also the use of "leans" seems odd, but without context I can't be sure. Is the meaning simply "uses"?

Comment: XYZ is the data warehouse where all the files are collected.